# How to set up SSL on WildFly 9 Domain Mode?

Tags: ssl, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I currently have a WildFly 9 cluster up and running with access to my application over port 8080, I would like to set up SSL and have access only on port 8443, but I cannot seem to find any documentation for where the security realm and https listener are placed in Domain mode.

I have the keystore and certificate all set up and was able to get https working in a demo using standalone mode, but I need to be able to do it in domain mode.

Can anyone help me out and share how they've accomplished this?

Comment: Hava you find the solution? I am also interested. So far I think servers in cluster must have same jks. On Domain Controler domain.xml should be configuration. But what to put there? PS; cluster nodes should be in a private network, with a firewall protecting them from outside attacks. Ideally isolated from workstations and laptops - but I have connection from LB that I must secure.

Comment: I posted the solution below. Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Thank you, it works form me too! One minor thing jboss.server.config.dir should be jboss.domain.config.dir than, and I think domain.xml is not needed on nodes but I must check that. I think http listener can be added like:  /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=default-https:add(socket-binding="https", security-realm="SSLRealm")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it!  It turns out for some reason JBoss was not registering my Security Realm and HTTPS listener.  To do this you need to use  bin/jbosscli and the commands:

RUN THE "CONNECT" COMMAND FIRST

```
/host=master/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/:add()
```

---where SSLRealm is the name of the realm

```
/host=master/core-service=management/security-realm=SSLRealm/server-identity=ssl/:add(keystore-path=Keystore.jks, keystore-relative-to=jboss.domain.config.dir, keystore-password=password)
```

---this assumes the keystore lives in the domain/configuration directory

Restart the server.

I then ran into issues figuring out the command to register the HTTPS listener, but I found the WildFly web console at serverURL:9990 has a way to do it too:

Once logged in to the webconsole
Configuration->Profiles->for each profile which is used->Undertow->HTTP->View

From there

HTTP Server->default-server->view

Finally

HTTPS Listener->ADD enter a name like: default-https, Security Realm: the name chosen for the security realm (for this example SSLRealm), Socket Binding: https and click save

Restart again

You should now have access at your serversURL:8443

To set it up on slave servers you should only need to copy the keystore to each slave servers domain/configuration and then add the security realm replacing /host=master/ with /host=slave/ in the command. And then restart the server.

Double check the Domain.xml file on the slave has the https listener you created originally in the webconsole (it should automatically be put into all of the clusters domain.xml files)